# logical OR column

Tags: python, matrix, dynamic-programming, logical-operators

What would be the most efficient approach to perform a logical OR (on 1's and 0's) on every column of a matrix in Python?

```
   0    0    0
   0    0    0
   1    0    1
   0    0    1
OR 0    0    1
   _    _    _
   1    0    1
```

Some context: I am employing a dynamic programming method for generating a table for a small project I'v been working on. I have 2 tables, one is 3-d and the other is 2-d. In the 3-d table only has 1's or 0's in it and the other has contains ints.

The 2-d table is generated as the 3-d one is, so I have to interleave them. The reason I want to OR an entire column is see if there was any 1's in it, if so the same column will contain a 1 in the 2-d table.

Example:

3-d table:

```
[1][i][j]
1000010000000000...
1000000001000000...
1000000000010000...
1000000000000001...

[2][i][j]
1000100000000000...
1000001000000000...
1000000001000000...
```

2-d table: 
(after OR'ing each column of the 3-d table, where the left-most most indices corresponds to a row in the 2-d table):

```
1000010001100001...
100010100000000...
```

Not sure if this is all clear...but thank you to anyone who helps! :D

I wont explain the method I used

Comment: See [bitwise operators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). Also probably reduce.

Comment: Can you use NumPy, or do you want something self-sufficient?

Comment: @DSM What's the code in `numpy`?

Comment: @DSM -- post your numpy code as a solution.  (no reason to keep us all in suspense ;^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you represent this data? If that's lists of lists, then swap last two indexes of a 3D-array, so "columns" can be accessed as sequential lists, and use `any`. That's about as fast as you can get in vanilla CPython: loop will be completely executed in C runtime.

Comment: Thanks, they are indeed lists of lists and this is the approach I implemented :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy`:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> m = array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]])
>>> m
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1]])
>>> m.any(0)*1
array([1, 0, 1])
>>> len('.any(0)*1')
9
```

Or, to be somewhat less concise:

```
>>> m.any(axis=0)
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> m.any(axis=0)*1 # make them ints
array([1, 0, 1])
```

If you have to work with pure Python, I'd actually do what @rkhayrov recommended, and if necessary keep transposing and index-shuffling to make referring to columns as easy as referring to lists.  But the ability to write `m[:, 0]` and `m[2:5, :]` is too handy for me to give up easily.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it.  reduce is falling into disfavor, as are map and filter.

```
col = 2
value = 0
for row in range(height):
    value |= matrix[row][col]
```

For python 2.x, use xrange instead of range.

Comment: `map()`, `filter()`, and `reduce()` are considered unpythonic in lieu of *list comprehensions*. For a *reduction* operation like the one above, `reduce()` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Joel: I think `reduce()` is not considered unpythonic because it can be replaced by a list comprehension (in fact, it cannot). Basically it's just because [Guido doesn't like it](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)

Comment: @NiklasB.: Ah. Of course. Hehe, I tried to replace `reduce()` with an list comprehension and the best I could do was  `z = lambda a, b=[1]: b.__setitem__(0, mul(b[0], a)) or b; [z(x) for x in range(1, 10)]` :)